# Define type to convert array of keyed object to indexed object in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to convert an array of `{key:'A',value:'B'}` to an indexed object `{A:{key:'A',value:'B'}}`. How can I define the return type to reflect the result object ?

```
function toObject<T = any>(a: Iterable<T & { key }>): { [k in /* !!not like this!! */ keyof T]: T } {
  return [...a].reduce((a, v) => (a[v.key] = v, a), {}) as any;
}

// Hope there is a hint for A and B
toObject([{key:'A',value:'B'},{key:'B'}]).A
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Niilo Keinänen, the answer is very close, I changed to param to array, also works.

```
const toObject = <K extends string, T = any>(arr: Array<T & { value: K }>): { [k in K]: T }  {
  const obj: any = { };
  arr.forEach(v => obj[v.value] = v);
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Do all the key-value-pairs have the same type of "value" (string in example case) ?

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen the value field is not matter, `toObject([{ key: 'first', value: 'second' }])= { first: { key: 'first', value: 'second' }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I understand correctly:

```
toObject({ key: 'first', value: 'second' })
= { first: 'second' } ?
```

This would seem to work:

```
const toObject = <K extends string, V, T extends { [P in K]: V }>(keyValuePair: { key: K, value: V }): T => {
    const obj: any = {}
    obj[keyValuePair.key] = keyValuePair.value
    return obj as T
}
```

Maybe you could also avoid the dirty *any* type somehow, not sure.